# Convert PostgreSQL function to PostgreSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, postgresql, stored-procedures, database-migration, aws-sct

I'm migrated a schema from oracle to postgreSQL using AWS-SCT, packages are converted to functions in postgreSQL.
I need to convert this function to procedure to compact with the code in the application middleware.

I've tried to convert to procedure, everytime i'm getting error like `SQL state: 42601` and `inout parameter are permitted`

Kindly help to convert the function to procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function "pk_audfreq$sp_audfreq"(
    OUT out_a double precision,
    OUT out_b double precision,
    OUT out_c double precision)
    RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN    
    SELECT
        MIN(audresponsetime), AVG(audresponsetime), MAX(audresponsetime)
        INTO STRICT out_a, out_b, out_c
        FROM public.audio_freq;        
    END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: If you want to return something, use a (set returning) function. Procedures aren't meant to return result sets.

Comment: tried, still giving syntax error SQL state: 42601,
Help required to correct the function to procedures in PostgreSQL without syntax error

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4dd53f81a866c0642a26d7b0dc2e81a

Comment: Alright. function which I had added above is working without any issues. my question is it possible to convert as postgreSQL procedure ?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if you look at this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html , it says "The mode of an argument: IN, INOUT, or VARIADIC. If omitted, the default is IN. ( **OUT arguments are currently not supported for procedures. Use INOUT instead.** )" . Could we use INOUT instead OUT ?

Comment: Sure you can use `INOUT`, but then you have to supply arguments. Why the insistence on using a procedure for something that naturally is a function?

Comment: And why the insistence on a function or procedure for a simple statement that would better be encapsulated in a VIEW

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have `OUT` parameters with procedures (yet). As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createprocedure.html) states:

> `OUT` arguments are currently not supported for procedures. Use `INOUT` instead.

Comment: Cool, I've created a procedure with INOUT, giving an error message `inout arguments are permitted`

Comment: Unless you show the relevant code and the complete error message, it is hard to help.